# ASP.NET Routing: predict which route will be executed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `RouteCollection` and a string with an URL. 
Has anybody an idea how can I get the name of the route that would be executed?

Some method like `RouteCollection.PredictRoute(url)` that will return the route name or the physical file that would be executed.

I want to create some statistics from web server log files. It would be very nice to reuse the used `RouteCollection` for that statistic.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this outside of your MVC application, where requests and contexts are not available (only the log files, as you mentioned).

Unfortunately, that is not very easy to do. In order to write such a matching method you need to reuse (or worse, rewrite) the MVC framework code for URL parsing found in various classes in namespace `System.Web.Http.Routing`. The source code is available on [CodePlex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), under Apache 2.0 license.

Instead, I think there's an easier way you can include the route names in the log files and use them later in statistics. Have a look below.

What you could to do is extend the default [`MvcHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchandler%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class and override its [`ProcessRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505193%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method. In there, you can call the base class implementation and right after it do your stuff by using [`RequestContext.RouteData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.requestcontext.routedata.aspx).

The class [`RouteData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.aspx) contains, besides other things, also the current route (which you defined in your route collection. That is accessible through the [`RouteData.Route`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.route.aspx) property.

This works because `MvcHandler` is always delegated (unless you've created your own MVC infrastructure) by the `MvcRouteHandler`, to handle the processing for each request. It is the one that gets the controller data from the existing route data, instantiates an `IController` implementation, and ultimately executes it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code I used to test that URLs were being mapped to their correct controller and action. You should be able to inspect the route name as well.

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes);
RouteData routeData = routes.GetRouteData(context);
string controller = routeData.Values["controller"];
string action = routeData.Values["action"];
```

The variable routes is a RouteCollection object and context is a HttpContextBase object.